# Force web application to use certain dll version C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, assemblies, web-config

I have a ASP.NET web application in which I have references to a couple of Class Libraries I developed.
Each of these libraries has a version number set in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

I would like to force the application to use only libraries with a specific version. i.e.

If I have User.dll of version 2.5.0.0 which is a referenced in the web application, and I try to copy in User.dll of version 3.0.0.0 I want the application to fail... or well just give me an error of some sort.

Also I do not want to store the assemblies in the GAC.

Is there some setting in web.config file I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx) the referenced assemblies with a strong name.

Comment: Ok I understand I have to sign the assembly, but then how will the application know what version it has to use ? Thanks for your help

Comment: When you reference a signed assembly the application will look for the particular version it is compiled against.

Comment: ... and if the versions/culture/public key tokens don't match a `FileLoadException` will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! When I replaced the dll with an older one I got the FileLoadException. The weird thing is when I replaced the old one with the original dll, it threw the exception again. I had to recompile the application for it to work. Is this normal? Really appreciate your help